# Deploying a Visual Studio C# project with database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing my C# application with database hosted on SQL server. I just need to know how to create an installer for the client. And what should I install on the client machine?

I tried publishing the application but database changed are not reflected, so what should I do?

I've tried searching on the internet how to publish this application and give it to the client, but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2012, SQL server 2012.

Comment: Maybe you could give us more information on what your application consists of and what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: If you are using the SQL Server to persist the application data you will need to install SQL Server Management Studio and the application.

Comment: Publishing the application only publishes the binaries required to run your application. If you are deploying to a client's machine, practically you have to deploy your database separately and configure your application to connect to that database.

Comment: A lot depends on the nature of your application and on the expectations and technical capability of your clients. What we usually do is include a administrative tool on our CD which is installed on the server. SQL Server Express is included as a pre-requisite of this. We also include an empty database, and another exe which is the db installer, which sets up serial number, licensing, etc. Then we wrap this in a .hta file which includes instructions on what to install in different scenarios, with links that run .msi files, and the db installer etc. Sounds like a lot of work? yes it is.

Comment: @Sparkss In fact you don't need SSMS under normal circumstances, although it can be a useful diagnostic tool.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies

My application is a simple expenses and revenues log for a mobile shop, it is a desktop application. I'm going to create it using c# and SQL server regarding DB is there any other alternative to create it (I mean which can help in publishing and coding)

Comment: For a simple application that is always single user ie not networked, I'd suggest you look at the LocalDB feature in SQLExpress. I've never used it myself, but AFAIK it's aimed at your kind of scenario

Comment: @peterG can I develop my application on SQL server enterprise but for the client install the SQL express?

Comment: Yes, you can, (assuming you aren't relying on any of the features in the higher-end versions of course, and I can pretty much guarantee you're not).  The core database functionality is the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are many posts online regarding deploying databases along with your web applications.  I would suggest using a Database Project to manage your database changes and installing the SQL Server Data Tools.

Here are a few tutorials:

[How to: Deploy a Database With a Web Application Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd465343(v=vs.100).aspx)

[SQL Server Data Tools Updated for Visual Studio 2012](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Blogs/Data-Driver/2012/09/SQL-Server-Data-Tools-Updated.aspx)

[Deploying Database Projects](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/deploying-database-projects)