# Vb app set up with database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Is it possible to make a setup installation of vb.net app including the database.

My database is SQL Server 2008. I've made a vb.net system and i just need to install it but the problem is im not the one who will install it . And so i figured out cause i try it once that i need to install sql server so that it would connct to the database, but the thing is i cant just tell them to nstall the sql server first and instruct to transfer the data and such.

Another thing is that it will be installed in different computer and so when i just use simple sql server, of course the connection of data source should be change and i cant possibly do that since they only want one installer.and what if they change their computer and cant i cant possibly always change the data source of connection.

WHat could be the other way to make a setup where i dont need to install sql server in a computer. A vb app where the setup contain the system and database that can easily be install.I already try installing it and ive already search or an answer and i still cant find one but is still hoping for a clear and detailed answer.

Comment: If you need a full Sql Server installation with a shared database access then your customers need to have that software installed somewhere in their LAN. Instead if you need only a single user access then you could look at [LocalDB installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc)

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020737/deploying-a-visual-studio-c-sharp-project-with-database#comment57779787_35020737). It's potentially not trivial - see my comment there for what I do.